# How could I restore the ribbon tabs to default?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon

I have one subsite. As you can see have of options are greyed out and I am missing Format text field. How could I restore the ribbon tabs to default?

[image]

Before all of this `Format Text` was there. Last time I had this issue I would have restored to previous version but now that didn't fixed it

Comment: You may not be having enough permissions to access all the options.

Comment: I have full admins rights. Even in this subsites group I am set as owner